# linux uinput: simple example?

Tags: linux, uinput

I'm having some problems getting *both* sides of code using `uinput` working.

Based on [Getting started with uinput: the user level input subsystem](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput)<sup>[dead link; [archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20170609022027/http://thiemonge.org:80/getting-started-with-uinput)]</sup> I put together the following *writer* (minus error handling):

```c
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int fd = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    int ret = ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_ABS);
    ret = ioctl(fd, UI_SET_ABSBIT, ABS_X);

    struct uinput_user_dev uidev = {0};
    snprintf(uidev.name, UINPUT_MAX_NAME_SIZE, "uinput-rotary");
    uidev.absmin[ABS_X] = 0;
    uidev.absmax[ABS_X] = 255;
    ret = write(fd, &uidev, sizeof(uidev));
    ret = ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_CREATE);

    struct input_event ev = {0};
    ev.type = EV_ABS;
    ev.code = ABS_X;
    ev.value = 42;

    ret = write(fd, &ev, sizeof(ev));

    getchar();

    ret = ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_DESTROY);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

That seems to work, at least the full `input_event` structure seems to be written.

I then wrote the most naive *reader* of events I could come up with:

```c
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int fd = open(av[1], O_RDONLY);

    char name[256] = "unknown";
    ioctl(fd, EVIOCGNAME(sizeof(name)), name);
    printf("reading from %s\n", name);

    struct input_event ev = {0};
    int ret = read(fd, &ev, sizeof(ev));
    printf("Read an event! %i\n", ret);
    printf("ev.time.tv_sec: %li\n", ev.time.tv_sec);
    printf("ev.time.tv_usec: %li\n", ev.time.tv_usec);
    printf("ev.type: %hi\n", ev.type);
    printf("ev.code: %hi\n", ev.code);
    printf("ev.value: %li\n", ev.value);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Unfortunately the reader side doesn't work at all; only manages to read 8 bytes each time, which isn't nearly a full `input_event` structure.

What silly mistake am I making?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should also be writing a sync event after the actual event. In your writer side code:

```c
struct input_event ev = {0};
ev.type = EV_ABS;
ev.code = ABS_X;
ev.value = 42;

usleep(1500);

memset(&ev, 0, sizeof(ev));
ev.type = EV_SYN;
ev.code = 0;
ev.value = 0;

ret = write(fd, &ev, sizeof(ev));

getchar();
```

Comment: Why is the sync event needed?

Comment: @dtmland Hopefully [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69530797) helps.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: The kernel expects an `EV_SYN` event of code `SYN_REPORT` because individual events may be grouped together, i.e., when they happen at the same point in time.

---

You can think of it as the kernel interpreting a *group of events* rather than individual events as specified in `struct input_event`. An `EV_SYN` event delimits these groups of events with `SYN_REPORT` as code, i.e., this provides a grouping mechanism for signaling events that occur simultaneously.

For example, imagine you touch with your finger on the surface of a touchpad:

[image: touchpad]

Given the definition of `struct input_event` in `linux/input.h`:

```c
struct input_event {
/* ... */
__u16 type;   /* e.g., EV_ABS, EV_REL */
__u16 code;   /* e.g., ABS_X for EV_ABS */
__s32 value;  /* e.g., the value of the x coordinate for ABS_X */
};
```

It isn't possible to create a single `EV_ABS` event that can hold both the codes `ABS_X` and `ABS_Y`, as well as the values for specifying the *x* and *y* coordinates, respectively – there is just a single `code` member in `struct input_event`<sup>1</sup>.

Instead, **two** `EV_ABS` events<sup>2</sup> will be created:

- One with the code `ABS_X` and the *x* coordinate as `value`.
- Another with the code `ABS_Y` and the *y* coordinate as `value`.

It wouldn't be entirely correct to interpret these two events as two events separated in time, i.e., one that indicates a change of the x coordinate and another that occurs later in time and indicates a change of the y coordinate.

Instead of two in-time-separated events, these events should be grouped together and interpreted by the kernel as a single *unit of input data change* that indicates a change of both the *x* and *y* coordinates *at the same time*. This is why the `EV_SYN` mechanism described above exists: by generating one `EV_SYN` event with the `SYN_REPORT` code just after these two `EV_ABS` events (i.e., `ABS_X` and `ABS_Y`), we are able to group them as a unit.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is directly related to the fact that a `struct input_event` is of fixed size and can't grow arbitrarily.

<sup>2</sup>Tecnically, more events may be created. For example, another event of type `EV_KEY` with the code `BTN_TOUCH` will likely be created. However, this is irrelevant for the point I want to make.