# How to simulate low-level scancode key press on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, keyboard, keyboard-events, custom-keyboard

I have notebook with this weird ASUS keyboard, where for some reasons in place of the `End` key there is `Power Off` ([Pictures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580902/how-to-change-mapping-for-the-poweroff-key-on-keyboard/828025#)). I want to undo the damage and let my Ubuntu Linux interpret this key as `End`.

I know how to intercept the `Power Off` using acpid and let it fire any command upon the keypress I want, as a root.

I would like it to emulate a scan codes  `0xe0 0x4f` followed by 50ms pause and then `0xe0 0xcf`.

**How to emulate a low-level keypress via scancode on modern Notebook and Linux?**

I tried writing the scancodes to the port using the following program

```c
/* gcc -O2 -s -Wall -osend_to_keyboard main.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/io.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i;

  ioperm(0x60, 3, 1);

  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    int x = strtol(argv[i], 0, 16);

    usleep(300);
    outb(x, 0x60);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

but nothing happened. Maybe the code doesn't work for my keyboard. I never did anything so low-level on Linux, so I lack proper experience.

---

For those of you who are laterally thinking: *I don't want to emulate keypresses on X only using e.g. xdotool.* ;-)

Comment: [linux uinput: simple example?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26693280/11654)